# Two active links at the same time on wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, anchor

I have this "problem" with my website that is, when i am at the Home Page i have another link of my menu that is not a page, who stays active because i used an anchor on that link.

Basicaly i added the **https://dama.ci/notre-histoire** url to that link so when i'm on another page of my website i can actually click on the link and go back to the home page where the anchor is attached and this is what causes the problem.

So my question is, since that link on the menu isn't a page what could i actually do to have the link activated only when it's clicked ?

Is there another way to achieve what i'm trying to have on the website ?

If you want to check the site [here is the URL](https://dama.ci/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with another way, you should remove current-menu-item class from that li onload using js i have added sample js code for you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".menu-item-538").removeClass("current-menu-item current_page_item");
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That totally solved my issue, never tought it was such a simple thing to do with js. That's perfect :D

Comment: I am feel happy, solve this issue.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your “Services” link URL from:

https://dama.ci/#inspiration

to simply:

/#inspiration

i.e. remember to add your domain’s trailing slash when you use the full or root-relative URL in your links.

When you say two menu items get highlighted at the same time, you mean “inspiration” and “Home”? If yes, you’ll need to make the “Home” link point to the top of the homepage (e.g. with a URL like /#inspiration). Otherwise, it gets highlighted by your theme as the current page.

Comment: I tried to do what you told me, but still no working, is there another way to get arround this ?

Comment: Hi, You can try with another way, you should remove current-menu-item class from that li onload using js i have added sample js code for you <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".menu-item-538").removeClass("current-menu-item current_page_item");
       });
    </script>